# Counting duplicate array results in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to simply count all the duplicates in an array and out put the array as a string with the amount of duplicates. This is what I have so far -

```
invent = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b'];

function inventItem () {
invent.sort();

var currentItem = null;
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < invent.length; i++) {
    if (invent[i] != currentItem) {
        if (count > 0) {
            newInventList = (currentItem + ' (' + count + ')');
        }
        currentItem = invent[i];
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    newInventList = (currentItem + ' (' + count + ')');
}
}
```

The problem is the variable `newInventList` is only storing the result `b (3)` I would like it to also have `a (1)`. So everything thats in the array does this mean I need to change the data type of `newInventList` to an array?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to count occurrences rather than just duplicates. One way to do this is to create a map of each item, and increment a counter for each occurence:

```
invent = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b'];
var occurences = {};

for (var i = 0; i < invent.length; i++) {
    var item = invent[i];
    var count = occurences[item] || 0;
    occurences[item] = count + 1;
}
```

You can then output your `occurences` however you want:

```
var output = '';
var items = Object.keys(occurences);

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    var item = items[j];
    output = item + ' (' + occurences[item] + ')'; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes change it to array and instead of assaigning variable to them append it like this:

newInventList.append((currentItem + ' (' + count + ')');